# Cordova + RequireJS: How load the File-Plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, requirejs, cordova-plugins

I want to store Files (Images) in my Cordova (3.6.4) App which is build with RequireJS.

I made a new Module but i don't know how to load the File-Plugin (org.apache.cordova.file) with RequireJS. window.requestFileSystem is always undefined. I thought i have to load the FileSystem (as commented in the module) but nothing worked...

```
define(function (require) {

"use strict";

var $ = require('jquery'),
    //FileSystem = require('/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/FileSystem'),


download = function (URL, Folder_Name, File_Name) {
    //step to request a file system 
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fileSystemSuccess, fileSystemFail);
},

return {
    download: download
};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it. It was an easy (and a little embarrassing) one. I simply forgot to load the cordova script itself because i didn't needed it to this point...

My app starts now with the following and everything is works.

```
require(['../cordova', '../cordova_plugins'], function () {
```

Comment: can you post your entire code please. How did you solve this? please elaborate more

Comment: I'm also interested in your solution: I'm getting an error if I manually include the plugins file, but it works if I only include the cordova one.